# Why do i get this result?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
SELECT * 
FROM afspraken
WHERE user_id =  '2'
AND datum >  '2012-06-05'
OR (
user_id =  '2'
AND datum =  '2012-06-05'
AND begintijd >=  '22:47'
)
ORDER BY datum DESC , begintijd ASC
```

This above is my query.. And while i should get zero result i still get one which is:

```
id  user_id     datum      begintijd    opmerking
114 2         2012-06-05    9:30        Deze afspraak is online gemaakt.
```

Now if i have this correctly, this query has 2 options to give results.. which is:
The user_id must be the same AND the date has to be higher then 2012-06-05.. Since its the same date this won't give the result..

Now the second option which is when the user_id is the same, the date is the same and when the beginningtime is the same or higher.. Now the time in the query shown is 22:47.. The time in the database is 9:30 morning.. How is 9:30 morning higher or equal to 22:47??

```
    id  int(10)                             
    user_id int(10) 
    datum   date    
    begintijd   varchar(5)
    opmerking   varchar(8000)
    reminder    int(10)
```

Comment: Is there a timezone conversion doing on?

Comment: I would suggest you do the query in two parts to determine which of the ORs are causing your issue.

First with user_id =  '2' AND datum >  '2012-06-05', and then with user_id =  '2' AND datum =  '2012-06-05' AND begintijd >=  '22:47'

Comment: And what datatype is the `datum` column? Actually, just post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ;-)

Comment: I just added my table columns.. And begintijd is indeed a varchar, think i should change this to Time i guess?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea would be to cast your time columns and values to Time:

```
SELECT CAST('20:05' AS Time) > CAST('9:06' AS Time) #returns 1 (compares times - what you want)

SELECT '20:05' > '9:06' #returns 0 (compares strings - not what you want)
```

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Comment: Or just use `TIME` fields in the first place.

Comment: Yes. As always, programming is nice because you can solve things differently. And obviously, setting the columns as time is the right approach :) But it's not always that you can modify table structure.

Comment: I have used the CAST instead of changing the column since the database is already on the server...

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your `begintijd` column is a `varchar` column.

So, as strings, `'22:47' < '9:30'`.

A solution would be to convert your `begintijd` column to a `time` datatype.

Comment: I just improved it (removed the unnecessary detail after OP clarified). I also included a possible solution, which was lacking in your original answer. You said why it happened, but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change your database layout why not use DATETIME like this:

```
id  int(10)                 
user_id int(10) 
afspraak_dt datetime    
opmerking   varchar(8000)
reminder    int(10)
```

Your data:

```
id  user_id   afspraak_dt       opmerking
114 2         2012-06-05 9:30   Deze afspraak is online gemaakt.
```

Examples selects:

```
SELECT * FORM afspraken WHERE user_id = 2 AND afspraak_dt > '2012-06-05 22:47'
```

Select all afspraken on that day for user id 2

```
SELECT * FORM afspraken WHERE user_id = 2 AND DATE(afspraak_dt) = '2012-06-05'
```

Select whith unix timestamp (select all afspraken in the future for user 2)

```
SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id = 2 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(afspraak_dt) > NOW()
```

The MySQL datetime has numerous select options for handling date and time. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html